# python pandas; tag inserted row of dataframe with narration on seperate column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe and code that inserts a rows based on the following.

For each row that has hours between >=10 and <=12, I need to:

1. change the total of the hours of the current row to 10
2. insert a duplicate row to the above and add the balance of hours to this row

For each row that has hours >12

4. change the total of the hours to 10
5. insert below a duplicate row to the above and 2 hours to this row
6. insert another duplicate row to the above and add the balance of hours to this row

```
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    df['number'] = (651,651,651,4267,4267,4267,4267,4267,4267,4267,8806,8806,8806,6841,6841,6841,6841)
    df['name']=('Alex','Alex','Alex','Ankit','Ankit','Ankit','Ankit','Ankit','Ankit','Ankit','Abhishek','Abhishek','Abhishek','Blake','Blake','Blake','Blake')
    df['hours']=(8.25,7.5,7.5,7.5,14,12,15,11,6.5,14,15,15,13.5,8,8,8,8)
    df['loc']=('Nar','SCC','RSL','UNIT-C','UNIT-C','UNIT-C','UNIT-C','UNIT-C','UNIT-C','UNIT-C','UNI','UNI','UNI','UNKING','UNKING','UNKING','UNKING')
    s =  df[df['hours'] < 10]
    s1 = df[df['hours'] > 12]
    s2 = df[df['hours'].between(10, 12)]

    df = pd.concat([
    s,
    s1.assign(hours=10), 
    s1.assign(hours=2), 
    s1.assign(hours=s1['hours'] - 12),
    s2.assign(hours=10),
    s2.assign(hours=s2['hours'] - 10)]).sort_index(kind='stable', ignore_index=True)

    print(df)
```

What I am trying to do:

a) For points 2 and 5 above I need to mark these rows in a new column as 'BHY3'

b) For point 6 I need to mark this row in the new as 'ATU1'

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the specifics of your aim are unclear and would benefit from example output. Here is a suggestion for getting started though: create your new columns in advance (before subsetting the data) and fill them in as you subset the data.

I cannot tell if you want both your duplicated rows and the rows you duplicated from to have the labels 'BHY3' and 'ATU1' or just the duplicated rows. This line of code is based on the idea that both should be labelled. You would simply add the following to where you defined your dataframe to create a column 'labeling' with the 'BHY3' label for all over 10 hours:

```
df['labeling'] = np.where(df['hours'] >= 10, 'BHY3', '')
```

If you only want to label the rows you duplicate in `s1` & `s2`, define the column as an empty string column and add your label after you subset the data. For example:

```
df['labeling'] = ''
s =  df[df['hours'] < 10].copy()
s1 = df[df['hours'] > 12].copy()
s2 = df[df['hours'].between(10, 12)].copy()

df = pd.concat([
s,
s1.assign(hours=10), 
s1.assign(hours=2, labeling='BHY3'), 
s1.assign(hours=s1['hours'] - 12, labeling = 'ATU1'),
s2.assign(hours=10),
s2.assign(hours=s2['hours'] - 10, labeling = 'BHY3')]).sort_index(kind='stable', ignore_index=True)
```

Your code (and therefore my lines to add to your code) may be longer than necessary. Once you have what you want working, you could probably shorten it through use of [np.where()](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/tutorial-add-column-pandas-dataframe-based-on-if-else-condition/) or [pd.DataFrame.where()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) or even [pd.apply()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-apply/). Then you may want to test which is more efficient.

Comment: thanks for your response.  I have added an example output.  Your response is close, I just however return NaN for the hours on the ATU1 rows

Comment: I found the small error in your code the first s2 within your concat should be s1

Comment: @ds882 just fixed that. Is it performing as you need now?